# XCode - Copy sqlite DB from simulator and copy onto device for testing

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I am working on a Core Data app, and have populated the sqlite file in the iPhone Simulator with all of the fixtures/data that I use to test the app.  I would like to use that sqlite file as a standardized set of testing data.

The devices that I test the app on all have different data sets, and I would like to standardize on the one in the simulator.

Is there a way in XCode (3 or 4) to add a step to the build/install process that will copy the sqlite file from the iPhone Simulator and install it over the file on the phone (if one exists)?

Thanks,
Neal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you locate the sqllite file in question, likely in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/{version}/Applications/{application id}/`, you can copy it to your project and add it to the build process. You'll want to copy it, for when you reset the sim.

On a couple of projects, I've added a unit test to determine if the 'default' sqllite database exists (I link it from the test build directory). Then, if the database is missing, I have the unit test create it (either using a text-file: csv or sql). Taking this approach has allowed me to later alter the schema, data, etc. It also allows me to run tests against the default database.

Comment: Interesting to put it in with the unit tests, but it doesn't really belong there.  This is indeed for testing, but I'm not sure that it exactly fits into the unit tests "box".  This seems to me to be something that fits better into the build/install process.  I've done some more digging and see that the new Xcode supports scripts in some way, so I'm wondering if that's the way to go...

Comment: I can relate to that perspective. My position is that if the 'default' database doesn't exist, the test fails (and then builds it). I then have an assertion that fails to inform me (and other devs) of the failure. The approach of a build script would also suffice.